# Can this plot_normal_distribution function be optimized?

Tags: r, performance, optimization

I've tried to optimize a function which I wrote a few weeks ago.
It got better but it is still slow. So I used `Rprof()` and found out `split()` takes the most time which for some reason makes me think this function can be a lot better.

Can it be done?!

```
normDist_V2 <- function(size=1e5, precision=1, ...)
{
  data <- rnorm(size) 
  roundedData <- round(data, precision) 
  framedData <- data.frame(cbind(data, roundedData))
  factoredData <- split(framedData$data, framedData$roundedData)
  actualsize <- (size)/10^precision
  X <- names(factoredData)
  Probability <- sapply(factoredData, length) / actualsize
  plot(X, Probability, ...)
}
```

Current speed:

```
system.time(normDist_V2(size=1e7, precision = 2)) #11.14 sec
```

Comment: Hello mr. Sampati. Could you post a sample of the data so that we can run the code as close to your environment as possible please?

Answer (score 0):

```
normDist_V2 <- function(size = 1e5, precision = 1, ...) {
  require(data.table)
  data <- rnorm(size)
  roundedData <- round(data, precision)
  framedData <- data.table(data, roundedData)
  actualsize <- (size)/10^precision
  dt <- framedData[, .N, keyby = roundedData]
  X <- dt$roundedData
  Probability <- dt$N/actualsize
  plot(X, Probability, ...)
}

system.time(normDist_V2(size=1e7, precision = 2)) # 1.26 sec
```

Comment: can you explain a little bit more what you've done and why it's faster (i.e. using `data.table`) ?